# Is it true that lightgbm can catch the linear trend or no

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, lightgbm

Let's imagine that I want to predict houses prices.
My data has a linear trend and seasonality and I want to use lightgbm for prediction.

I know how to catch seasonality - I can add mean encoded features.
But is it possible to catch the trend?
I think that no because the base of lightgbm is trees and there is no linear part. Am I right or wrong?

Comment: Are you referring trend as time series component in data?

Comment: yes, I see that price for houses growing over time

Answer (score 0):

Any decision tree can't capture time relation directly. But you can use create some time based features which have time relation in them, such as `Lag feature`. It almost worked with tree based model.

Basic idea of lag feature is to attach prev history of some time period with current sample. More you can find [here](https://gallery.azure.ai/CustomModule/Generate-Lag-Features-1)

Comment: Thank you! I can't understand how tree-based models capture lag features. As I know tree-based models have fixed outputs. If my dataset contains 2019 year and I want to make a prediction for the 2020 year, and targets for 2020 about twice bigger then for 2019 then even if I will use the lag feature and algorithm will understand that this lag means that value should be equal something, it still can't predict twice bigger target because train dataset doesn't have such values. Or somewhere could be hidden magic with the linear part?

Comment: Let's say, you want to predict price for tomorrow, now you may guess that this prediction can be depend on last $7$ days history, or may be last $1$ month or more. So you just feed the data for that time period along with current time sample. Same analogy can be apply on your above requirement.

Comment: You may wanna to look at this [notebook](https://www.kaggle.com/zoupet/predictive-analysis-with-different-approaches) for implementation detail.